# Pass reference type by ref

Tags: c#

I know when we pass reference type by value to a method ,pass a copy of the reference and If you change a value inside the reference type, this will also change the value outside the method as well,so when we pass reference type by reference in C#? because it seem same.

Comment: What do you mean by "when we pass a reference type by value"?

Comment: See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: The difference is , if you pass `reference type by ref`, you can then assign new instance from the method into which you passed it

Comment: link is not working  @JoeSewell

Comment: @zahrabayat It's working for me. Site also appears up in general: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jonskeet.uk?proto=https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be clear since `string` is reference type

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "old value a";
        string s2 = "old value b";
        
        Method1(ref s1, s2);
        
        Console.WriteLine(s1); // <-- this is what `ref` can do
        Console.WriteLine(s2);
    }
    
    public static void Method1(ref string a, string b)
    {
         a = "new value a";
         b = "new value b"; 
    }
    
    
}
```

output

> new value a
> old value b

Comment: I think this is a bad example as string is an immutable reference type which can only be changed through ref. That doesn't explain why one would write a method `void PassStringBuilderByRef(ref StringBuilder sb) { ... }` which is nicely explained by Jon Skeet in the link @joe-sewell provided in his comment to the answer.

Comment: @Lemmes When you talk about string immutability, this is only to explain that actual object behind string can't be changed and you create new one each time. String is really an array of `char`. What `ref` can do to you? `Method(ref char[] arg)` and `Method(ref string arg)` - what is the difference if you assign new object to `arg` in both cases? Point is the same. `arg` is a pointer and you assign new memory location to it. And without `ref` you copy the pointer with no ability to reassign memory. Example stands

Comment: Now you're mentioning the important point - the part about "newing" an object. And that is what I was criticizing in your example: it doesn't explain - in my opinion - why one would use a - to be explizit - normal mutable class like `StringBuilder` as ref parameter to a method. So your comment to the question is better than your answer to the question because of the use of string. That was my point.

Comment: @Lemmes "newing" is a slang of phony programmers. Good ones say "instantiating". Now. The question here is about `ref` and not about "mutable classes". What is the difference when you pass by reference and in your method do `s = new StringBuilder()` vs `s = "ABC"`? There is no difference because `"ABC"` is a syntactical sugar for `s = new string(new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C'})`. This is just a coincident that in `StringBuilder` you can change content and in `string` you can't. Similarly, you can't change in objects from  `System.Collections.Immutable`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

When you pass a variable by **value** to a method, you are actually passing a **copy** of the value of that variable to the method. Since the value of a reference type is the **reference** that the type refers to, So When you pass a reference type variable by **value** to a method, you are passing a copy of this reference to the method and Because of this, If you change a value of the variable inside the method , this will also change the value outside the method as well.

when you assign the new instance to a variable of reference type ,you are actually saying that variable refer to the new reference and because of you just pass a copy of the value and not a reference of reference type, you can't assign the new instance to a variable inside a method but in passing a reference type by `ref` , you are passing a reference of reference type and because of this you can assign the new instance to a variable inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario other than string

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Say that we have a method for creating a `Person`

**Version-1**

```
public static void CreatePerson(Person p, string name)
{
    p = new Person(){ Name = name};
}
```

**Version-2**

```
public static void CreatePersonV2(ref Person p, string name)
{
    p = new Person(){ Name = name };
}
```

> Throws object reference exception since john still refer to null

```
    Person john = null;
    CreatePerson(john, "John");
    Console.WriteLine(john.Name);
```

> But this will work since we passed david by reference

```
    Person david = null;
    CreatePersonV2(ref david, "David");
    Console.WriteLine(david.Name);
```

Comment: This is an excellent example.  Add a textual explanation that is clearer and better written than the one by Zahara Bayat (which appears to be technically correct but is almost impossible to follow), and you will probably start receiving upvotes.